# How to synchronise point-coordinates and PIL affine image transformation on a Tkinter canvas GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

I am modifying an existing interactive Tkinter image viewer GUI (original code: https://github.com/ImagingSolution/PythonImageViewer) by adding functionality to draw lines over the image, and for these lines to stay in the same place relative to the image when the image is panned and zoomed. The utimate aim being to extract the coordinates for those line segments for analysis afterwards.

When the image is transformed, it is re-drawn with an affine transformation, where the transformation matrix (mat_affine) is defined in the 'translate()' and 'scale()' functions. I have attempted to apply the same matrix transformation to a global list of coordinates (line_coords) that updates with the image, and then re-draw lines from these new updated coordinates.

**However,** the lines drawn from these transformed coordinates move relative to the transformed image - so clearly the transformation isn't achieving the desired behaviour.

Below is a stripped-down version of the code, you'll need to open up an image of your own (File -> Open), and draw a line (right click start and end points of the line), then zoom (mousewheel) or pan (click-drag), to replicate the behaviour - note the line isn't removed, but moves beyond the visible canvas area:

```
import tkinter as tk            
from tkinter import filedialog, simpledialog  
from PIL import Image, ImageTk  
import math                    
import numpy as np              
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

line_coords = []

class Application(tk.Frame): 
    
    # Initialisation and window properties
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master.geometry("600x400") 
        self.pil_image = None 
        self.line_start = None
        self.my_title = "PyPointCounter"
        
        self.create_menu()
        self.create_widget()

        self.reset_transform()
    
    # Menu bar
    def create_menu(self):
        self.menu_bar = tk.Menu(self) # Menu
        self.file_menu = tk.Menu(self.menu_bar, tearoff = tk.OFF)
        self.menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.file_menu)
        self.file_menu.add_command(label="Open Image", command = self.menu_open_clicked)
        self.master.config(menu=self.menu_bar)
        
    def menu_open_clicked(self, event=None):
        filename = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(
            filetypes = [("Image file", ".bmp .png .jpg .tif"), ("Bitmap", ".bmp"), ("PNG", ".png"), ("JPEG", ".jpg"), ("Tiff", ".tif") ],
            initialdir = os.getcwd()
            )

        self.set_image(filename)
    
    # Create canvas
    def create_widget(self):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master, background="black")
        self.canvas.pack(expand=True,  fill=tk.BOTH)
        
        # bindings
        self.master.bind("<Button-1>", self.mouse_down_left)                   # MouseDown
        self.master.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.mouse_move_left)                  # MouseDrag
        self.master.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.mouse_wheel)                     # MouseWheel
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-3>", self.start_line)     # Right mouse button for drawing lines
    
    # Load image file
    def set_image(self, filename):
        if not filename:
            return
        self.pil_image = Image.open(filename)
        self.draw_image(self.pil_image)
        os.chdir(os.path.dirname(filename))
    
    # USER ACTIONS
    # -----------------------------------------
    def mouse_down_left(self, event):
        self.__old_event = event

    def mouse_move_left(self, event):
        if (self.pil_image == None):
            return
        self.translate(event.x - self.__old_event.x, event.y - self.__old_event.y)
        self.redraw_image()
        self.__old_event = event
    
    # zoom mouse wheel action
    def mouse_wheel(self, event):
        if self.pil_image == None:
            return
        if (event.delta < 0):
            self.scale_at(1.25, event.x, event.y)
        else:
            self.scale_at(0.8, event.x, event.y)
        self.redraw_image()

    def reset_transform(self):
        self.mat_affine = np.eye(3)
    
    # Pan
    def translate(self, offset_x, offset_y):
        mat = np.eye(3)
        mat[0, 2] = float(offset_x)
        mat[1, 2] = float(offset_y)
        self.mat_affine = np.dot(mat, self.mat_affine)
    
    # zoom base function
    def scale(self, scale:float):
        mat = np.eye(3)
        mat[0, 0] = scale
        mat[1, 1] = scale
        self.mat_affine = np.dot(mat, self.mat_affine)
    
    # zoom at mouse location
    def scale_at(self, scale:float, cx:float, cy:float):
        self.translate(-cx, -cy)
        self.scale(scale)
        self.translate(cx, cy)
    
    # line drawing with two right mouse clicks - start and end points
    def start_line(self, event):
        if self.line_start is None:
            self.line_start = (event.x, event.y)
        else:
            end_point_x, end_point_y = event.x, event.y
            self.canvas.create_line(self.line_start[0], self.line_start[1], end_point_x, end_point_y, fill='red')
            line_start = tuple([self.line_start[0], self.line_start[1]])
            line_end = tuple([end_point_x, end_point_y])
            line_coords.append([line_start, line_end])
            self.line_start = None
    
    #-----------------------------------------------
    
    # Update display according to user actions
    def draw_image(self, pil_image):
        
        self.canvas.delete('all') # remove previously drawn lines
        
        # IMAGE TRANSFORMATION
        if pil_image == None:
            return

        self.pil_image = pil_image

        canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        
        mat_inv = np.linalg.inv(self.mat_affine)

        affine_inv = (
            mat_inv[0, 0], mat_inv[0, 1], mat_inv[0, 2],
            mat_inv[1, 0], mat_inv[1, 1], mat_inv[1, 2]
            )

        dst = self.pil_image.transform((canvas_width, canvas_height),Image.AFFINE,affine_inv,Image.NEAREST)
        im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=dst)
        item = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0,anchor='nw',image=im)
        self.image = im    
        
        # LINE COORDINATE TRANSFORMATION
        def transform_line_coords(i):
            original_coords = line_coords[i] # original coordinates
            homogeneous_coords = np.column_stack((np.array(original_coords), np.ones(len(original_coords))))
            transformation_matrix = self.mat_affine.T
            transformed_coords = np.dot(homogeneous_coords, transformation_matrix)
            cartesian = transformed_coords[:, :2]
            start_point = tuple([cartesian[0,0], cartesian[0,1]])
            end_point = tuple([cartesian[1,0], cartesian[1,1]])
            return [start_point, end_point]
             
        # overwrite original line coordinates [[(x1_start,y1_start), (x1_end,y1_end)], [(x2_start,y2_start), (x2_end,y2_end)]...], 
        # with transformed cordinates.
        global line_coords
        line_coords = [transform_line_coords(i) for i in range(0, len(line_coords))]
        
        # re-draw the lines defined in the global list of lines
        def draw_line(i):
            x1 = line_coords[i][0][0]
            y1 = line_coords[i][0][1]
            x2 = line_coords[i][1][0]
            y2 = line_coords[i][1][1]
            self.canvas.create_line(x1,y1,x2,y2, fill='red')
        
        draw_lines = [draw_line(i) for i in range(0, len(line_coords))]
        
    def redraw_image(self):
        if self.pil_image == None:
            return
        
        self.draw_image(self.pil_image)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

I've tried for a day or two to work out whats going on, but I can't see why the matrix transformation for the lines isn't achieving the same results as the matrix transformation for the image. I wonder if there is some other image repositioning happening when the image is redrawn, or if there is a mismatch between window, canvas and image coordinate systems? I am also not sure why the image transformation takes the multiplicative inverse of the transformation matrix?

I would consider myself an intermediate level coder in python, but have very little experience in GUIs. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You just need to add dragging the line to the mouse_move_left method using self.canvas.move() and to the mouse_wheel method to resize the line proportionally.

Comment: Thank you @СергейКох, this approach has worked - it's far simpler and more effective than my attempts. For anyone reading, I've implemented this and posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comment from @СергейКох, I have implemented the line transformations within the `move_mouse_left` and `mouse_wheel` methods, using the `canvas.move()` and `canvas.scale()` functions respectively.This is far simpler (and probably much more efficient) than trying to transform the line coordinates manually by a transformation matrix.

Just to note I have added an additional line of code within the `draw_image` method to ensure the lines are rasied above the image when the image is re-drawn; so that they are still visible:

```
[self.canvas.tag_raise(i) for i in line_ids]
```

Code updated with solution below:

```
import tkinter as tk            
from tkinter import filedialog, simpledialog  
from PIL import Image, ImageTk  
import math                    
import numpy as np              
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

line_ids = [] # Store line object IDs as a Global list

class Application(tk.Frame): 
    
    # Initialisation and window properties
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master.geometry("600x400") 
        self.pil_image = None 
        self.line_start = None
        self.my_title = "PyPointCounter"
        
        self.create_menu()
        self.create_widget()

        self.reset_transform()
    
    # Menu bar
    def create_menu(self):
        self.menu_bar = tk.Menu(self) # Menu
        self.file_menu = tk.Menu(self.menu_bar, tearoff = tk.OFF)
        self.menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.file_menu)
        self.file_menu.add_command(label="Open Image", command = self.menu_open_clicked)
        self.master.config(menu=self.menu_bar)
        
    def menu_open_clicked(self, event=None):
        filename = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(
            filetypes = [("Image file", ".bmp .png .jpg .tif"), ("Bitmap", ".bmp"), ("PNG", ".png"), ("JPEG", ".jpg"), ("Tiff", ".tif") ],
            initialdir = os.getcwd()
            )

        self.set_image(filename)
    
    # Create canvas
    def create_widget(self):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master, background="black")
        self.canvas.pack(expand=True,  fill=tk.BOTH)
        
        # bindings
        self.master.bind("<Button-1>", self.mouse_down_left)                   # MouseDown
        self.master.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.mouse_move_left)                  # MouseDrag
        self.master.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.mouse_wheel)                     # MouseWheel
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-3>", self.start_line)     # Right mouse button for drawing lines
    
    # Load image file
    def set_image(self, filename):
        if not filename:
            return
        self.pil_image = Image.open(filename)
        self.draw_image(self.pil_image)
        os.chdir(os.path.dirname(filename))
    
    # USER ACTIONS
    # -----------------------------------------
    def mouse_down_left(self, event):
        self.__old_event = event

    def mouse_move_left(self, event):
        if (self.pil_image == None):
            return
        delta_x, delta_y = event.x - self.__old_event.x, event.y - self.__old_event.y
        self.translate(delta_x, delta_y)
        self.redraw_image()

        [self.canvas.move(i, delta_x, delta_y) for i in line_ids]  
        self.__old_event = event
    
    # zoom mouse wheel action
    def mouse_wheel(self, event):
        if self.pil_image == None:
            return
        if (event.delta < 0):
            self.scale_at(1.25, event.x, event.y)
            [self.canvas.scale(i, event.x, event.y, 1.25, 1.25) for i in line_ids]
        else:
            self.scale_at(0.8, event.x, event.y)
            [self.canvas.scale(i, event.x, event.y, 0.8, 0.8) for i in line_ids]
        self.redraw_image()

    def reset_transform(self):
        self.mat_affine = np.eye(3)
    
    # Pan
    def translate(self, offset_x, offset_y):
        mat = np.eye(3)
        mat[0, 2] = float(offset_x)
        mat[1, 2] = float(offset_y)
        self.mat_affine = np.dot(mat, self.mat_affine)
    
    # zoom base function
    def scale(self, scale:float):
        mat = np.eye(3)
        mat[0, 0] = scale
        mat[1, 1] = scale
        self.mat_affine = np.dot(mat, self.mat_affine)
    
    # zoom at mouse location
    def scale_at(self, scale:float, cx:float, cy:float):
        self.translate(-cx, -cy)
        self.scale(scale)
        self.translate(cx, cy)
    
    # line drawing with two right mouse click - start and end points
    def start_line(self, event):
        if self.line_start is None:
            self.line_start = (event.x, event.y)
        else:
            end_point_x, end_point_y = event.x, event.y
            line = self.canvas.create_line(self.line_start[0], self.line_start[1], end_point_x, end_point_y, fill='red')
            global line_ids
            line_ids.append(line)
            self.line_start = None
    
    #-----------------------------------------------
    
    # Update display according to user actions
    def draw_image(self, pil_image):
        
        # IMAGE TRANSFORMATION
        if pil_image == None:
            return

        self.pil_image = pil_image

        canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        
        mat_inv = np.linalg.inv(self.mat_affine)

        affine_inv = (
            mat_inv[0, 0], mat_inv[0, 1], mat_inv[0, 2],
            mat_inv[1, 0], mat_inv[1, 1], mat_inv[1, 2]
            )

        dst = self.pil_image.transform((canvas_width, canvas_height),Image.AFFINE,affine_inv,Image.NEAREST)
        im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=dst)
        item = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0,anchor='nw',image=im)
        self.image = im
        
        [self.canvas.tag_raise(i) for i in line_ids]
        
    def redraw_image(self):
        if self.pil_image == None:
            return
        
        self.draw_image(self.pil_image)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```